# Sorting scatter chart in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a problem with setting proper order of x axis in scatter chart. There is a code:

```
df <- data.frame(first = c("a", "b", "c"),
       sec = c(1, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$first <- factor(df$first, 
                            levels = c("c", "a", "b"))
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = df$first, y = df$sec, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tozeroy')
```

[image: Output]

On axis categories are sorted correctly, but values aren't.
Do you have any ideas how I can fix it?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is the desired output? The x axis is in the order of your levels which you set to `c("c", "a", "b")`.

Comment: The x axis is in proper order, but the line firstly goes to b then to a. When there are more values it caused that chart is messed up

Comment: Ok, I found solution. It's necessary to set order of dataframe based on levels, only for scatter type it's important, because for bar chart everthing works fine.

Comment: Great that you've found a solution! Please post it as an answer and accept it, so later others can find your solution more easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, it's necessary to set order of dataframe based on factor levels:

```
df <- df[order(df$first),]
```

I think only for scatter type it's need to be done, because sorting bar chart works fine without adding above line.